# Add full active drop-shadow from figma for any icon

Tags: android, padding, dropshadow, figma

I want add drop-shadow in drawables for use them on any android icons (navbars, custom views, buttons). Then should get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO1N9.png). Trying with ninepatch and layer-list or just png. It works, but there is a problem: due to the shadow, paddings of drawable increases, as a result, main picture becomes smaller. And it becomes impossible to use such a layers-list in selector with other images for example. What can do about it?

Comment: PLease share some code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just used shadow png bitmap as background for vector image like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector_active_with_sunshine" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector_inactive" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Where `ic_vector_active_with_sunshine`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drop_shadow" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector" />
</layer-list>
```